# i need to get alldata whereclause in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need to take all data if Page!=@page, get AllDATA

select count(page) as TARIH,
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap as SIRA
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between @date1 and  @date2  and Page=@page or Page = AllDATA

Comment: You're going to need to give us a little bit more information.  I have no idea what you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: why all the down votes? isn't it obvious that english is not their primary language?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select
    count(page) as TARIH
        ,(datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap as SIRA
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between @date1 and @date2 and (Page=@page or Page = AllDATA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
select count(page) as TARIH,
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap as SIRA
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between @date1 and  @date2  and (Page=@page or @page='Tüm Kullanıcılar')

Comment: that is what I said 44 minutes ago! you need ( ) around your OR condition

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(page) as TARIH,
(datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap as SIRA
from scr_SecuristLog
where 
    Date between @date1 and @date2 
    and 
    (
        (@page is not null and Page=@page) 
        or (@page is null and @page=@page)
    )
```

will return all data between date1 and date2 and only data equal to the parameter, or if the parameter is null will return all data between date1 and date2